# Netbeans 12.0 Not showing errors and attribute colors in java classes

Tags: java, netbeans

I am currently working on a project for my first java team project. I have run into an issue where a certain class will suddenly stop showing errors (when I try to build my project, the output will show an error as shown in the screen capture, but I won't see an error in the text editor). I wrote a bunch of nonsense at the last line for you to see what I mean. Also, my attributes normally show in purple text and they now show in white text which is normally the indicator that the class in question won't show errors. This only affects some classes, most of them I worked on recently and have not been committed and pushed to my gitlab repo.

This makes coding a pain since I never know if I have made a stupid mistake until I try to build the project. I have not fiddled with the IDE, the only thing I did was change the font to the Jetbrains one and put on the default Netbeans dark theme.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Here is the screen grab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete Netbeans `Cache` folder (after closing Netbeans of course). On Windows systems it is usually located under `C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\`.

Comment: This fixed it! For those with the same issue, the Appdata folder is hidden so you will have to go in the explorer menu and change the settings so you can delete the cache folder.